# Combine first character with every other of a word

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner !

Can anyone explain me please how can I combine the first letter of a word with every other letters from the same word using loops?
I mean if I write the word "book" (or any word) on the console, the output be:
     bo
     bo
     bk

Comment: What did you try? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Extending @nvoigt comment, welcome to SO! Please show us what you've tried, what isn't working and expected output so we can further help you. There are a few ways to accomplish this, but without seeing what you are working with, answers will not be geared towards what you are working with rather opinionated answers.

Comment: Your example doesn't match your request. If it's every other letter than the output is `bb bo`... Maybe it needs to say `with every letter from the same word` perhaps?

Comment: *If its every letter opposed to my comment above*, it's still wrong, it would be `bb bo bo bk`...

Answer (score 3):

Approach with a simple for-loop

```
string input = "book";
for (int i = 1; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(input[0], input[i]));
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/hl3orX

Comment: Thank you ! This looks better for me ! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
string word = "book";

word.Skip(1)
    .Select(c => word.First().ToString() + c)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Don't forget `using System.Linq;`

However, this might not be what your teacher had in mind, so please consult your book.

Comment: A suggestion..Wouldn't `".Select(c => $"{word.First()}{c}")"` better than `.Select(c => word.First().ToString() + c)`

Comment: @AnuViswan thats sugar... Can you explain `better than` in terms of what exactly?

Comment: @AnuViswan both approaches work, I think that's a question of personal taste. This approach will even run at .NET 3.5

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Thanks for pointing it out... :)

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ `$"{word.First()}{c}"`will be translated into  `string.Format("{0}{1}),word.First(),c)"`

Comment: @fubo I know what it does, I asked Anu what he thinks it's doing... thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I suppose he wanted to tag me, tagged you by mistake :)

Comment: @AnuViswan haha, yeah, it happens :)

Comment: Thank you ! But is a little to complicated for my level :)

Answer (score 2):

Sound a bit like a quick puzzle and is maybe a better post for [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

```
private string CharBanging(string word)
{
  string output = string.Empty;
  for (int i = 1; i < word.Length; i++)
    output += $"{word[0]}{word[i]} ";

  return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        string word = "book";
        for (int i = 1; i < word.Length; i++ )
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{word[0].ToString()}{word[i].ToString()}"); 
        }
```

Comment: Thank you ! Is nice for me to see so many helpful answers :)

Comment: Both of the `.ToString()` expressions can be removed from this answer.  This is unnecessarily verbose.  `$"{word[0]}{word[i]}"`

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a simple solution to your question. Let's go trough each character of your word using the string as an array. Have in mind that in my example i am not doing any kind of sanity checks/validations

```
string word = "book";
for (int currentChar = 1; currentChar < word.Length; currentChar++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{word[0]}{word[currentChar]}");
}
```

`word[0]` would be printed on each iteration, then `word[currentChar]` would take the current character depending on the iteration.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate you answer and your explications ! :)